Why is Callgrind not working on my project?
I tried using callgrind on my program written in C language but it is not working. This is the output it gives me when I try to launch it:
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBeyJRYf.png)
It was working before, but I changed a couple of things in the code and it stopped working.
I also eliminated the flag "fsanitize" from the makefile but it is still not working.
Do you have any idea on why is it not working?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Is the program starting/running, when started without callgrind/valgrind?

Your exe is still linked with address sanitizer. Did you clean everything?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
